# Angular - Weird Behaviour on page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

The website is opening ok and I am able to navigate to different pages without any issue. However, when I have the home page open and I hit refresh button the website breaks and returns following message

```
{"seek":"21598","duration":"1:00:08"}
```

I am not sure what is causing it. Because it is not so for any other page.

You can view the website by clicking **[HERE](https://www.sunnytextiles.pk)**

My app-routing looks as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
   {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
   *** Other Routing
   {path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

My .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Apache `.htaccess` config?

I don't see it as an Angular routing issue. It seems a server navigation as it is returning 301 code. You can check it by openning Dev tools on Networks tab and do the refresh. It redirects /home to /home/ and gets some value there.

Comment: updated the original question by including .htaccess file

Comment: Can you try to add a dot before /index in the last line? `RewriteRule ^(.*) ./index.html [NC,L]`

Comment: added the . before /index.html as you recommended. didn't solve the issue

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try to comment the rules and check that the issue is from .htaccess?

Comment: firs tried commenting that line and then even completely commented the .htaccess file and the issue remains so i doubt it is because of .htaccess file

Comment: On this page there are no redirects. I even tried commenting all code on the page to cross it from the list. The error still persisted.

Comment: forced redirection of /home fixed the issue